# Regex to variable assignment fails in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I am wondering why the following fails to assign the value (the ip address) of the regex match to the $ipaddress variable after it is matched. I've tried a number of recommended methods (I'm new to Perl obviously), but they've all failed. When performing matches, is it not true that each match is stored in the $1 variables, which range from 1-9, so that the first is, by default, $1?

Code is:

```
sub block_match {

  my $line_instance_b = $_[0];
  my $ipaddress;

  if ( $line_instance_b =~ /banned_ip|Found UltraSurf Signature|ip_block / ) {
    $ipaddress = $1 if ($line_instance_b =~ /\b(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b/);
    print "Found ip address: ", $ipaddress, "in the following line: \n",
    $line_instance_b;
  }
  else {
    print "Not a block line: \n", $line_instance_b, "\n"
  }
}
```

The line it is matching against is:

```
INIT: banned_ip add 208.67.219.132 for FreeGate
```

Comment: In list context a match returns a list of the captures, you can do `my ($ipaddress) = $line_instance_b =~ /…/` instead. Additionally, the pedant in me must point out that your regex completely precludes the possibility of IPv6 addresses, which eventually *will* bite you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re using a non-capturing group, `(?:...)`, which is never assigned to a match variable.

Wrap the `(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}` part of the expression in `()` to capture into `$1`:

```
$ipaddress = $1 if $line_instance_b =~ /\b((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3})[0-9]{1,3}\b/;
#                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Jon. That did work, and now I know what to read over again as well. Thanks for taking the time :)